# Foreign/related data with WCF RIA Domainservice in LightSwitch

Tags: foreign-keys, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LightSwitch application where I need to aggregate data and being able to edit it. I followed Eric Erhardts [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/08/how-do-i-display-a-chart-built-on-aggregated-data-eric-erhardt.aspx) which works fine. Then in the DomainService class I added this to make updates possible:

```
public void UpdateRuleEntriesById(RuleEntriesById ruleEntryObject)
        {
            var origRuleEntry = (from RuleEntriesById in this.Context.RuleEntries
                                 where RuleEntriesById.Id == ruleEntryObject.Id
                                 select RuleEntriesById).FirstOrDefault();

            origRuleEntry.Country = ruleEntryObject.Country;
            this.Context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This works fine aswell and I can edit and save the Country attribute in the RuleEntry table. However Country is an entity of it's own and I want it to appear as an AutocompleteBox, as it would if I imported my database without using a RIA Service. I imagine I need to tell that Country is a foreign attribute to the Country table or something, but where and how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Aggregated* data is usually displayed as **read-only**, because it's a **summary** of a number of different records. It doesn't really make sense to try to allow editable properties in an *aggregated* entity at all. Which of the underlying records are supposed to get the changed data?

If you're creating a **new** entity (that's combining properties from two tables, but **not** representing aggregated data), all you should need to do, for LightSwitch to display a combo box for any property, is to add a property to your RIA service entity, that is of the same type as the related entity. Does that make sense?

Remember, that you create the **shape** of your new entity, but LightSwitch knows **nothing** about the implementation of it (which is entirely handled by you). If you need to be able to edit it, you have to provide the appropriate properties & methods (which it sounds like you're already doing successfully for the methods). LightSwitch then handles the displaying & editing of the entity for you, & it's again up to you how you handle any changed data. Again, does that make sense?